# user friendly method to obtain Gmail user credentials on a windows application

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am writing a windows C#.Net application using .Net3.5. I am trying to download emails from Gmail using Google's [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-cs) ( a requirement). Is it possible to get user credentials in a user friendly way (browser page popping up requesting credentials, supplying username and password directly into my application, or whatever), rather than having the user [obtain the credentials himself](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pop up a browser window with the required URL for the user to grant access (or even embed a browser window in your application!)  The user should then simply just see the requested permission and click OK and then your application can get the access token.

See:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed

Better to search/tag on [google-oauth]